# How to have proper borders for excel worksheet cells, excel export in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, export-to-excel, xls

In my index action of the controller I have got this:

```
def index
    @vehicles = Vehicle.all
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.xls
    end
end

I have got this in my index.xls.erb template:
 <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Manufacturer</th>
        <th>Model</th>
        <th>Version</th>
        <th>CC</th>
        <th>BHP</th>
      </tr>
    <% @vehicles.each do |vehicle| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= vehicle.manufacturer.name %></td>
        <td><%= vehicle.model %></td>
        <td><%= vehicle.version %></td>
        <td><%= vehicle.engine_cc %></td>
        <td><%= vehicle.power_bhp %></td>
       <% end %>
  </table>

 and I have registered the mime_type for xls like this:
 Mime::Type.register 'application/vnd.ms-excel', :xls
```

But this does not have usual cell borders that MS Excel shows.     tried what was suggested in Railscasts i.e., http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel.     but that leads basic input / output error while trying to open the file (may be file is malformed in that case). any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to create valid excel data from rails, please have a look at axlsx.
In the spirit of full disclosure, I am the author of the gem, but it really is the best thing out there for making excel (xlsx) documents.

You can find out more about the gem here:
https://github.com/randym/axlsx

And there are tutorials for using it in rails here:
http://axlsx.blog.randym.net/

There are also some secondary gems like acts_as_xlsx and axlsx_rails that make model exports and report generation very easy.

If you have any questions, you can also usually find me (JST) in

## axlsx on freenode.

With axlsx, you would do something like this:

```
require 'axlsx'
p = Axlsx::Package.new
p.workbook.add_worksheet(:name => 'vehicles') do |sheet|
  sheet.add_row %w(Manufacturer Model Version CC BHP), :style => Axlsx::STYLE_THIN_BORDER
  @vehicles.each do |vehicle|
    data = [vehicle.manufacturer.name, vehicle.model, 
            vehicle.version, vehicle.engine_cc,
            vehicle.power_bhp]
    sheet.add_row data, :style => Axlsx::STYLE_THIN_BORDER
  end
end
p.serialize('vehicles.xlsx')
```

There is a lot more you can do as well, like custom styling, charts, hyperlinks, images etc.
Please give it a go if you think it fits your development style.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, used axlsx gem !

Comment: is there a way to insert values into a particular column, in my case add current date into Pth column before populating more data in the following rows ?

Comment: use add_row [nil, nil, nil, Time.now] where nil values are the columns you wish to skip.